# Taking the VAR value outside of promise function

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I have to get the value of `count` to execute the `for loop`, how can I get it? I have provided the sample code below:

```
var listCount = usersPage.trOfRowInListPage.count();
        listCount.then(function (realListCountValue) {
          console.log(realListCountValue);
        });
        expect(listCount).toEqual(6);
        for(var i=1; i<listCount; i++)
        {
          console.log(i);
        }
```

Now, my problem is, the for loop is not being executed. Thanks!

Comment: does `listCount` return a promise?

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the loop into the `then()`:

```
var listCount = usersPage.trOfRowInListPage.count();
listCount.then(function (realListCountValue) {
    for(var i=1; i<realListCountValue; i++)
    {
        console.log(i);
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry.. No way to take outside?

Comment: @DeepakSabastein if you need a real count value, you would have to put it into `then()` anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming listCount is a promise, this should help you. Your for loop was comparing `i` to a promise, rather than a number. I think what you wanted to do was to compare it to the result of the promise, like so:

```
var realValue, listCount = usersPage.trOfRowInListPage.count();

listCount.then(function (realListCountValue) {
    realValue = realListCountValue;
});
for(var i=1; i<realValue; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: No, I am not getting the desired output, I think you understood right.. "realvalue" or "listCount" is working outside for "expect", but not for "for" loop. I think we are not getting the integer value outside the promise function, any other way?

Comment: what does `realListValue` return? It doesn't look like `listCount` returns a promise

Comment: "listCount" returns long text data but "realListCountValue" returns exact count as an integer..